# Email break line doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

When I'm trying to send an email with *type* `text/html` that contains break lines `<br/>`, I get an email with break lines that are not parsed like the following:

```
Hello Mr.Test,<br/> Welcome to test world<br/>Regard,<br/>x
```

I also tried to use `nl2br` without luck.

Comment: @jeroen Read the subject dude

Comment: @DesignStudios Oooooops, I think I'll call it a day...

Comment: @jeroen could i know please , why you vote down my question?

Comment: @user1391482 I haven't. But you need to post code and `var_dump()`'s of the relevant variables in order to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution is by add | raw to message body , in email twig template.

Comment: Nothing to do with Swift bundle as it is about twig template language. Thanks mate you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

If you sending with HTML in PHP try:

```
 $message .= "Hello Mr.Test". "<br>" . "Welcome to test world" . "<br>" . "Regards"."<br>". "x";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the content type when you create your message object. Otherwise the client will read it as plain text.

`$message->setContentType("text/html");`

Comment: Yes i already specify the content type as i mention in my question , but without luck.